# Django. How to customize the raw_id_field to add many related object in one go?

Tags: django, django-admin

Actually, the raw_id_field option gives you a magnifying glass button next to the field which allows users to search for and select a value. You are obliged to select only one value at time. There is no way to select more than one values before adding.

Is there any way to get the link generated by the raw_id_field option, pull out a full-featured edit/select window? A window in which you can select more than one object that will be added to the raw_id_field?

Thanks a lot for advices and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. For more details, just read this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6396)